# How to get all the documents uploaded by the user in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, dashlet

I am new to alfresco. 
Is it possible to get list of all the documents created and uploaded by the user and populating these values in a custom dashlet?

Comment: Is it only for the Explorer client or Share?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index it will tell you about all the webscripts currently available. If you can, you probably want to use an existing webscript to get your data, though writing your own one isn't too bad - [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts) would get you started.

I think that for your use case, the "user feed" should give you the info you need. Visit http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/repository/activities/feed/userfeed.get when your repo is running and it'll tell you the details about the webscript

Answer (score 1):

Hmm If it's in Share then you have a content tab on the user profile, which shows all the users content. You can load that webscript into the Dashlet.

[image]